# React-native build fail to IOS when add firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native

I'm trying to export an application for IOS, but when I add the firebase library to the project, when exporting for IOS I get an error BUILD FAILED.

I've already followed the official documentation, I've even followed several tutorials but the errors are the same.

Build in XCODE the errors are:
Could not build module 'os_workgroup'
CABASE - Could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
CFNETWORK - Could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
CFStream - Could not build module 'Dispatch'
CGBase - Could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
CLErrorDomain - Could not build module 'Foundation'
CoreImageDefines - Could not build module 'CoreGraphics'
CTFontTraits - Could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
CVBase - Could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
dispatch - Could not build module 'os_workgroup'
EAGL - Could not build module 'Foundation'
Foundation - Could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
ImageIOBase - Could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
IOSurfaceBase - Could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
main - Could not build module 'UIKit'
module - Redefinition of module 'Firebase'
MTLTypes - Could not build module 'Foundation'
NSAttributeString - Could not build module 'Foundation'
NSFileProviderDomain - Could not build module 'Foundation'
NSString+UserNotifications - Could not build module 'Foundation'
React-Core-umbrella - Could not build module 'UIKit'
SecBase - Could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
UIKit - Could not build module 'Foundation'
vecLibTypes - Could not build module '_Builtion_intrinsics'
Yoga-umbrella - Could not build module 'UIKit'

I removed the firebase library and tried to export to both platforms and everything worked.

I removed the DerivedData file, pod file and node_module file and reinstalled everything and it was the same.

the files podfile, AppDelegate (#import <Firebase.h>)  have the same settings as explained in the documentation, i try to change to #import 'Firebase.h' but is the same.

My info

System:
OS: macOS 13.1
CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
Memory: 1.85 GB / 32.00 GB
Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 19.2.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v19.2.0/bin/node
Yarn: Not Found
npm: 9.2.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v19.2.0/bin/npm
Watchman: 2023.01.09.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335
Xcode: 14.2/14C18 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 11.0.17 - /usr/bin/javac
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0
react-native: 0.70.6 => 0.70.6
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
*react-native*: Not Found

Any suggestion? Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `@react-native-firebase/app` and `@react-native-firebase/messaging`.

Open `Podfile` in `ios` diectory and add these lines:

```
pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
```

in between

```
flags = get_default_flags()
```

and

```
use_react_native!(
```

Then, delete `podfile.lock`.

In your terminal inside your project root directory, run the following commands:

```
cd ios
pod deintegrate
pod cache clean --all
npm cache verify
yarn cache clean
pod install --repo-update
```

Next, clean build folder under `XCode -> Product -> Clean Build Folder`.

Run your app once from within XCode. You can then subsequently run your app from the terminal.

=====================

If for some reason you encounter this error

```
"No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initialzeApp()"
```

open `AppDelegate.mm` add and this

```
#import <Firebase.h>
```

below

```
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
```

Search for a block of code containing `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and add the code below at the beginning of the code block

```
if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
  [FIRApp configure];
}
```

So, you would have something like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  # Firebase configuration
  if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
    [FIRApp configure];
  }
  
  # rest of the code below which you shouldn't touch 
  # unless you absolutely know what you are doing
  ...
```

This should send the error packing.

Cheers!!!